# Send player position to another player to move him in multi player game using Unity Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I follow the steps of PUN basic tutorial.
For now I reach to a part of what I want **Send my position in the current time to another player with me in the room to move him**. I can print my position each time I update it , what I need is to know how I can send position to another player to move him.
Let's say I have a desktop player and when I move him this translation moving the player on mobile.
And how I stop instantiate object on mobile, I just want to deal with the instantiated object on desktop. 
I am using unity and Photon Network SDK.

Here is the code I used

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkCharacter : Photon.PunBehaviour {

    private Vector3 correctPlayerPos;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!photonView.isMine)
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, this.correctPlayerPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);

        photonView.RPC ("PrintPosition", PhotonTargets.All, transform.position);
    }

    void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.isWriting)
        {
            // We own this player: send the others our data
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
        }
        else
        {
            // Network player, receive data
            this.correctPlayerPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void PrintPosition(Vector3 pos)
    {
        Debug.Log (pos);
        //I need to send position coordinates to the other device
    }
}
```

The other class of establish multiplayer environment:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : Photon.PunBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("0.1");
        //PhotonNetwork.logLevel = PhotonLogLevel.Full;
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString());
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby ()
    {
        Debug.Log("join lobby!");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
    }

    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed()
    {
        Debug.Log("Can't join random room!");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null);
    }

    void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("join random room!");
        GameObject monster = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("monsterprefab", Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUN has some new components since their new update.
I'd recommend you to use those components because it is really user friendly towards new users.

Some components you could use:

- PhotonTransformView
- PhotonRigidbodyView
- PhotonAnimatorView

These three components will help you sync your position, physics and animations on the GameObject it is attached to.

If you do not want to use these components i suggest you search up: interpolation and extrapolation for Unity PUN.

Some good starting tutorials:

- [SkyArena PUN Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8St-bqfmufA&list=PLQ0PnSAYGlIb2UdVapw-yfn7-r9w7JFbk) This is a really good video tutorial[in parts] on PUN so you should definitely check that out.
- [Exit Games Marco Polo](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/tutorials/tutorial-marco-polo) This tutorial is created by someone from PUN also really good to read even if you don't need it.

Hope this will help you.

-Menno

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in Demo Synchronization that provided in PUN plugin, it is really helpful.

Comment: The youtube video from the developers of SkyArena has a good explanation for the synchronization, it's really similar to the Demo Sync from PUN plugin.
So I suggest checking some of these videos out.